# Форматирование телефонных номеров C#

Tags: c#

Требуется отформатировать строки, содержащие телефонные номера, так, чтобы их можно было потом сравнить. К примеру:

> 8(495)430-23-97
>   +7-4-9-5-43-023-97
>   4-3-0-2-3-9-7

являются одинаковыми номерами телефона. Как привести их к виду 8<код><номер>, чтобы потом их можно было сравнить и сказать, совпадает ли данный номер с введенным или нет? 
P. S. +7 = 8. Если код не указан, то он по умолчанию равен 495

Comment: Просто сделай то, что ты сейчас написал. 
Или напиши, в чём конкретно проблема с примером кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта функция все форматирует до нужного вида путем удаления/добавления нужных элементов

```
static string Remove(string s)
    {
        s = s.Replace("-", "");
        s = s.Replace("--", "");
        s = s.Replace("+7", "");
        s = s.Replace("8", "");
        s = s.Replace("(", "");
        s = s.Replace(")", "");
        s = s.Replace(" ", "");
        if (s.Length < 7)
            s = s.Insert(0, "495");
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: `s = s.Replace("8", "");` а если ввели номер содержащий **8** не только на первом месте, например **8-800-300-83-83**, **8-800-224‑22-22**, **+7 (495) 640-10-88**?

Comment: Тогда нужно просто проверить, стоит ли 8 на первом месте

Comment: ну дополните свой код этой проверкой, отредактировав ответ  :)  будем посмотреть дальше, что вам это даст;  пока что вы просто пытаетесь удалить с _первого места_ код страны, что в любом случае не является _приведением к виду 8<код><номер>_